# Traversing a binary tree and returning a value

Tags: java, binary-tree, traversal

Can someone please explain to me what's wrong with my code.  It's suppose to traverse through the whole tree and return the the point closest to the query point.

```
public Point2D nearest(Point2D point) {
    Point2D nearest;
    if (root == null) {
        return null;
    }
    nearest = nearest(root, point, root.point);
    return nearest;
}

private Point2D nearest(Node node, Point2D point, Point2D candidate) {
    if (node == null) {
        return candidate;
    }
    if (point.distanceTo(node.point) < point.distanceTo(candidate)) {
        candidate = node.point;
    }
    nearest(node.leftBottom, point, candidate);
    nearest(node.rightTop, point, candidate);
    return candidate;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code with print statements? Maybe that might help.

Comment: Spent hours trying to debug to no avail.

Comment: Hi, in order for us to help properly you need to say what incorrect behavior you're seeing and exactly what you'd expect. An example, possibly with a diagram in the case of trees, would help a lot.

Comment: Hint: you're recursively calling `nearest`, but ignoring the return value...

Comment: While trying to debug I used the simple example of a tree with only 3 nodes in it with the points: [0.5, 0.5] [0.4, 0.4] [0.6, 0.6].  I called the nearest function to point [0.7, 0.7].  I expect it to return [0.6, 0.6] but instead it returns [0.5, 0.5]

Comment: @JonSkeet, I don't get it.  Every time I find a new shorts distance value I pass it on to the next node query. Shouldn't it be passed along throughout the whole traversal and return at the end?

Comment: @user2573222: Are you expecting the call to `nearest` to change the value of `candidate` in the calling method? That's not going to happen. Arguments are passed by value in Java. Don't forget, the caller is only going to see what the *first* call returns... not what the *innermost* call returns.

Comment: @JonSkeet You should write it up as an answer, not hint at it in comments.

Comment: @JonSkeet So what would be an appropriate way for achieving my goal? Sorry, still new to java and programing.

Comment: @user2573222: Well think about what you want to *use* the result of the recursive call. I *suspect* you just want `candidate = nearest(...);` instead of calling the method and ignoring the result...

Comment: Not really (or I missed something), only right part can be returned then. results from left and right parts have to be compared...

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks, got it. (although still a bit foggy re recursion).

Answer (score 0):

> ...still a bit foggy re recursion

Sounds more like you are a bit foggy re local variables.

When a function is called, Java pushes an *activation record* (AR) onto the call stack.  The AR holds all of the function args and local variables.

When a function returns, its AR is popped off the stack and discarded, and all of its args and locals disappear.

Each call gets its *own* AR.  Therefore each recursive call to `nearest(...)` gets its *own* `candidate` variable.  When your code calls `nearest(...,candidate)`, the new activation changes *its* `candidate` variable but that has no effect on the caller's `candidate`.  The `candidate` in the inner activation gets thrown away when the inner call returns.  That's what Jon Skeet meant when he said "Arguments are passed by value."

You can only pass arguments *in* to a function.  To get aything back out, you either have to use the return value, or else you have to pass *in* a reference to some object that the function can modify.

Comment: James, thanks for the detailed explanation.  It is much clearer now.